# Yesod update forms and delete views

Tags: yesod, yesod-forms

I'm building my first Yesod web application after many years of building Django ones. I'm used to having update forms and delete views built in to Django. That doesn't seem to be the case with Yesod, at least I can't find them referred to in the [book forms chapter](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms) or in any [online examples](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki).

For clarity what I'm calling an update form would be a form pre-populated with values of a model instance, which you'd use to edit an instance. A delete view is just a built-in function for deleting an instance. For the latter I've done the following just now:

```
deleteArticleR :: BlogId -> Handler Html
deleteArticleR blogId = do
    runDB $ delete blogId
    redirect $ BlogR
```

I haven't gotten how I'd do an update form just yet. I'm happy to roll my own as above but I wanted to double-check here whether there were any built in first. Have I missed some docs? If so, where might I find them?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "update and delete forms?" I can't think of anything that could be called a "delete form," but "update form" should be covered by the standard form usage described in the forms chapter, unless I'm misunderstanding your goal.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I've edited the question. 'Delete forms' was poor terminology on my part. Love the framework so far by the way, so thanks for it.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you're looking for with update forms? https://github.com/fpco/stackage-server/blob/master/Handler/Profile.hs

Comment: I think probably yes. I presume if I wanted to use the same code for both create forms (no model instance) and update forms (model instance) I'd use something like `blogForm :: Maybe Blog -> AForm Handler Blog`?

Comment: Exactly, that's the way the library is designed.

Answer (score 0):

Yesod's Github repository appears to have some CRUD helpers inside the `yesod-form`  package: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/yesod-form/Yesod/Helpers/Crud.hs.

Comment: Just letting you know I've seen this and will look at it soon. I've gone my own way for now but will definitely check this out as a refactor.